# Is there a reason why dispatch.yaml doesn't seem to route to specified microservices when I locally run my Node.js app which contains microservices?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, microservices, dispatch

Eventually, I want to deploy a Node.js app which contains microservices to Google Cloud Platform. I develop locally. However, my dispatch file doesn't seem to route to the associated modules.

My dispatch.yaml file looks like this:

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch :
  - url    : "*/service-1/*"
    module : service-1

  - url    : "*/service-2/*"
    module : service-2
```

In the same map exists the app file for the main app:

**app.js**

```
"use strict"

const express = require('express')
const app     = express()

app.get('/',     function(req, res){res.status(200).send('Main app: Hello, world!')})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Main app server listening on port ${PORT}`)})
```

Per (micro)service I've created a potentially autonomous application-map.
Here is the example for the first microservice.

**service-1/app.js**

```
"use strict"

const express = require('express')
const app     = express()

app.get('/service-1/', function(req, res){res.status(200).send('Service 1: Hello, world!')})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`service-1 server listening on port ${PORT}`)})
```

When I start the main app's server through the terminal and then go to `localhost:8080`
in my browser: it responds as expected. The message 'Main app: Hello, world!' is received.

However, when I type in `localhost:8080/service-1` in the browser, it doesn't respond as it should.

Does anyone know why? Or does dispatch.yaml only work when actually deployed?

Thank you for your time.

I appreciate help very much.

Answer (score 1):

The dispatch file works locally, but only with the local development server, i.e. with the standard environment.

But since you're using Node.js it means you're running in the flexible environment, for which local development means running a server for each of your services, on different ports. Your two `app.js` seem to be configured for the same port: 8080.

And indeed, you can't really use `dispatch.yaml` locally in this case, you need some other method to build cross-referencing URLs based on these ports for local development.